# remove ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, constraints, cascade, alter

I have a child table. and foreign key there with ON DELETE CASCADE while creating the table.

There are no records either in child or parent table.

I want the primary key, foreign key to be as they are but want to remove only the CASCADING option from the child table .

is there anyway that i can Alter that child table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_departamento` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_departamento` (`id_departamento`),
  CONSTRAINT `departamentos_direcciones_pedidos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_departamento`) REFERENCES `departamentos` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

1. First drop foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE departamentos_direcciones_pedidos DROP CONSTRAINT departamentos_direcciones_pedidos_ibfk_1;
```

2. Second, create the correct foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE departamentos_direcciones_pedidos ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_departamento) REFERENCES departamentos(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
```

The default is NO ACTION.

So try altering your child table back to default.

Comment: fid number(5) references parent(pid) on delete cascade;

so i need to issue     alter table child modify fid on delete set default..... right ?

Answer (score 1):

(Oracle) You can only alter the state of a constraint. ON DELETE is not a state. So you need to drop constraint and recreate it.

```
drop table t1 cascade constraints;
create table t1 (id number unique, rid number constraint t1_fk references t1(id) on delete cascade);

alter table t1 drop constraint t1_fk;
alter table t1 add constraint t1_fk foreign key(rid) references t1(id);
```

if you're using Oracle there are different dictionary views which might help you to recreate the constraint correctly

Answer (score 1):

- Export the database as a `.sql` file
- Then press `ctrl + H` to replace all `ON DELETE CASCADE` with ""
- Then drop the tables from the DB and use the new file to instantiate a new one without `ON DELETE CASCADE`